# Switching to multi-row index in dataframe created form list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a function which creates `DataFrame` from list of lists:

```
def logs_reader():
    path = Path("C:\\Users\\" + getpass.getuser() + "\\DCBviz\\logs\\")

cols1 = ['Station ID', 'Reciever type', 'Satellite system', 'Date installed', 'Date removed']
cols2 = ['Station ID', 'Antenna type', 'Cable length', 'Date installed', 'Date removed']

file_list = [f for f in path.glob('**/*.log') if f.is_file()]
receivers_data = []
antennas_data = []
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        station_id = re.findall("Four Character ID\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        
        receiver_types = re.findall("Receiver Type\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        satellite_sys = re.findall("Satellite System\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        date_installed = re.findall("Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)T.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        date_removed = re.findall("Date Removed\s*:\s*(.*?)T.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        
        antenna_types = re.findall("Antenna Type\s*:\s*(.*?)\s.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        cable_lengths = re.findall("Antenna Cable Length\s*:\s*([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)\s.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        antenna_date_installed = re.findall("Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)T.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        antenna_date_removed = re.findall("Date Removed\s*:\s*(.*?)T.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
        
        receivers_data.append([station_id, receiver_types, satellite_sys, date_installed, date_removed])
        antennas_data.append([station_id, antenna_types, cable_lengths, antenna_date_installed, antenna_date_removed])
        
        d = []
        
        for l in receivers_data:
            d.append({'Station ID': l[0]*len(l[1]), 
                  'Reciever type': l[1], 
                  'Satellite system': l[2], 
                  'Date installed': l[3][0:len(l[1])],
                  'Date removed': l[4][0:len(l[1])]})
        df = pd.DataFrame(d)   
return df

df = logs_reader()
```

and as a return i have dataframe which looks like that:
[image]

and i want to split the lists from colums 2-6 and create single entries of pure stings with `Station ID` as multi-row index. How can I do that?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: It would help greatly if you created a simple dataframe show your problem and expected output from this simple data.

Comment: You are lookong for something like [df.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) but be careful, expoding several columns in succession will give you `n*m*p*q*r` rows

Comment: Do all the lists have the same length? You might be better off creating separate dfs in your discovery function, collecting them in a dict with `'Station ID'` as keys, and concatenating all dfs with `df = pd.concat(dict.values(), keys=dict.keys())`

Comment: No, they are of different lengths

Comment: @RichieV so how i need to modify this function to create separate dfs as you said?

Comment: since the different lists in a single row are of different lengths, please provide an expected output (which you can manually make in excel) of just the first row of from your df...

Comment: @RichieV i've modified the question so now they are of the same lengths, what's next?

Answer (score 0):

So you have your regexed data in lists

```
receiver_types 
satellite_sys 
date_installed
date_removed
    
antenna_types
cable_lengths
antenna_date_installed
antenna_date_removed
```

Now I am assuming that each file corresponds to ONE `station_id`, still the line `station_id = re.findall(...` will return a list.

Then you will have a `station_id` which is a list of length 1 and a bunch of other lists. If all the receiver lists are of the same lenght, you can create a df and collect it in `receivers_data` with the code below (please copy it again as I removed the brackets around `station_id`). And then do the same for `antennae_data`.

Notice your current code is discarding `df` on each iteration and only returning data from the last file that was read.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, *if all lists in the same row are of same length*, then the best option is to create a df from each file and concatenate them after the loop

You can replace the line

```
receivers_data.append([station_id, receiver_types, satellite_sys, date_installed, date_removed])
```

with

```
receivers_data.append(
    pd.DataFrame(
        [station_id * len(receiver_types), receiver_types, satellite_sys, date_installed, date_removed],
        columns=list_of_column_names
    )
)
# or instead of a list use a dict with file_name as keys
```

After you are done reading all files you can concatenate both lists with

```
df_receivers = pd.concat(receivers_data)
df_antennae = pd.concat(antennae_data)
```

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstaniding. Yes, they are of the same length but after the second `for` loop is done. And I am getting df which is on the screen.